# Using google.colab.auth.authenticate_user() on local machine get OperationalError

Tags: authentication, google-colaboratory

I tried to authenticate in order to use GCP resource such as BigQuery and Cloud Storage in a jupyter notebook running on a local machine.

1) pip install google-colab
2) Run this in a cell:

```
from google.colab import auth
auth.authenticate_user()
```

I cut/paste in the auth code but got:

```
OperationalError                          Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-5-93f8cbc33ddf> in <module>()
      1 from google.colab import auth
----> 2 auth.authenticate_user()
      3 print('Authenticated')

/Users/kelvinchan/tmp/python3_env/deeplearning/lib/python3.7/site-packages/google/colab/auth.py in authenticate_user(clear_output)
    146     with context_manager():
    147       _gcloud_login()
--> 148     _install_adc()
    149     colab_tpu_addr = _os.environ.get('COLAB_TPU_ADDR', '')
    150     if 'COLAB_SKIP_AUTOMATIC_TPU_AUTH' not in _os.environ and colab_tpu_addr:

/Users/kelvinchan/tmp/python3_env/deeplearning/lib/python3.7/site-packages/google/colab/auth.py in _install_adc()
    106   gcloud_db_path = _os.path.join(
    107       _os.environ.get('DATALAB_ROOT', '/'), 'content/.config/credentials.db')
--> 108   db = _sqlite3.connect(gcloud_db_path)
    109   c = db.cursor()
    110   ls = list(c.execute('SELECT * FROM credentials;'))

OperationalError: unable to open database file
```

It appears I miss quite a bit of setup that need to be done on my local machine.

Answer (score 2):

`google-colab` should be removed from pip given its misleading branding.

The package isn't authored by Google, and the libraries don't work outside of the Colab environment.

Comment: Is this a "hack" project someone did?

Comment: How can we authenticate if we dont use google-colab? I want to authentication from file.py and not from file.ipynb.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to see authentication methods found, e.g., on https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/authentication/getting-started#python

Those lead to two solutions:

- end-user credentials: https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/authentication/end-user-installed
- Service Account key: https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/authentication/service-account-file

According to Bob Smith's answer the `google.colab` is meant to be used within Colab environment.